# How to write converted files to another directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

I am new to python and a beginner at the language. I have the following problem, I am trying to batch convert html files to excel files. The problem is I don't know how to go about writing the new excel file to another folder, I end up re-coding the html files to excel as far as I can tell.

```
from html2excel import ExcelParser
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()  # Get the current working directory (cwd)
files = os.listdir(cwd)  # Get all the files in that directory
print("Files in %r: %s" % (cwd, files))

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\Desktop\Afternoon')

cwd = os.getcwd()  # Get the current working directory (cwd)
files = os.listdir(cwd)  # Get all the files in that directory
print("Files in %r: %s" % (cwd, files))

inputFolder = r'C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\Desktop\Afternoon' ## Change here the input folder
outputFolder = r'C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\Desktop\Evening' ## Change here the attachments output folder

for file in os.listdir(inputFolder):
    if file.endswith(".html"):
        parser = ExcelParser(file)
        parser.to_excel(file)
```

Error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\PycharmProjects\Batch HTML to Excel\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    parser = ExcelParser(file)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\html2excel\excel\parser.py", line 7, in __init__
    super().__init__(file_path)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\html2excel\base\parser.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.load_workbook()
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\html2excel\excel\parser.py", line 30, in load_workbook
    self._write_cell(i, j, col_data)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\html2excel\base\parser.py", line 47, in _write_cell
    self.ws.cell(row=row, column=col).value = val
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 215, in value
    self._bind_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 194, in _bind_value
    value = self.check_string(value)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 162, in check_string
    raise IllegalCharacterError
openpyxl.utils.exceptions.IllegalCharacterError
```

Desired outcome:
Program converts each html file in the "Morning" folder from html to excel and writes/saves the new excel  file in the "Evening" folder.

I have done a lot of research but I haven't been able to find anything that works.

P.S.

The following code works for single files in the desktop, it is the source of my attempted code.

```
from html2excel import ExcelParser

input_file = r'C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\Desktop\088TE QTIF-794.html'
output_file = r'C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\Desktop\088TE QTIF-794.xlsx'

parser = ExcelParser(input_file)
parser.to_excel(output_file)
```

Comment: Looks like it is an encoding error, are you specifying the correct encoding?

Comment: The excel parser module that I am using is the one specifying the encoding, it is doing it correctly as it worked for a single file conversion, my problem is with multiple file conversions.

Comment: In your sample code you have `parser = ExcelParser(INPUT_file)
parser.to_excel(OUTPUT_file)`, while in your loop you use `file` both times, so the output file has `html` extension.

Comment: @Pietro, thanks that solves the first problem, now how do I write it into evening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work with minor tweaks:

```
from pathlib import Path

# change the paths to wherever you need
afternoon_folder = Path("afternoon")
evening_folder = Path("evening")

for aft_file_path in afternoon_folder.iterdir():

    # aft_file_path is the path to a generic file in the afternoon folder
    print(f"aft_file_path {aft_file_path}")

    # get the extension of this file
    ext = aft_file_path.suffix
    print(f"    ext {ext}")

    # skip all non-html files
    if not ext == ".html":
        print(f"    skipping {aft_file_path}")
        continue

    # this path has the correct extension, but is in the wrong folder
    excel_path_afternoon = aft_file_path.with_suffix(".xlsx")
    print(f"    excel_path_afternoon {excel_path_afternoon}")

    # extract the name and append it to the right folder
    excel_path_evening = evening_folder / excel_path_afternoon.name
    print(f"    excel_path_evening {excel_path_evening}")

    # now you can use aft_file_path and excel_path_evening as input and output files
    # parser = ExcelParser(aft_file_path)
    # parser.to_excel(excel_path_evening)
```

I tested on this folder structure:

```
.
├── afternoon
│  ├── input00.html
│  ├── input01.html
│  ├── input02.html
│  └── skipthis.txt
├── evening
└── snippet.py
```

And this is the output:

```
aft_file_path afternoon/input00.html
    ext .html
    excel_path_afternoon afternoon/input00.xlsx
    excel_path_evening evening/input00.xlsx
aft_file_path afternoon/input02.html
    ext .html
    excel_path_afternoon afternoon/input02.xlsx
    excel_path_evening evening/input02.xlsx
aft_file_path afternoon/skipthis.txt
    ext .txt
    skipping afternoon/skipthis.txt
aft_file_path afternoon/input01.html
    ext .html
    excel_path_afternoon afternoon/input01.xlsx
    excel_path_evening evening/input01.xlsx
```

I obviously cannot test the parsing part of the code, as I do not know what is inside the `html` files.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you Pietro, I found your method useful for another issue I am facing. I'll be saving this for that project.

Comment: Does this not work if you put the correct paths in `afternoon/evening_folder` and uncomment the `parser` lines? Do you still get the `IllegalCharacterError`?

Comment: After seeing your comment I gave it another go, I had made an error in the file path, it works like a charm! However it still produces the following error:
`raise IllegalCharacterError
openpyxl.utils.exceptions.IllegalCharacterError`
It produced it at the same file as my solution, file number 264, I am not sure why it works for the rest but stops there, which is a 1/10th of the way, as there are 2303 files in total.

Comment: @Ahmed Then the problem must be the content of the file, I'm going out on a limb here and say there is an illegal character somewhere ;-) Without access to the files I cannot help you: if it does not contain private data (and it's reasonably small) upload the file that raises the error and I can try to look for it.

Comment: I cannot say how much I appreciate your help my friend, unfortunately the file is indeed confidential, and I came to the same conclusion as you, that there is an illegal character, I might have to open another question for this problem. Thanks a million once again :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, thank you to Pietro for pointing out my error.

Secondly, I got this working but not 100%, it converts all the files to excel but I can't give them their original names, as it does nothing and produces no error when I run it trying to keep their original names.

```
from html2excel import ExcelParser
import os

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\Desktop\Afternoon')
cwd = os.getcwd()  # Get the current working directory (cwd)
files = os.listdir(cwd)  # Get all the files in that directory
print("Files in %r: %s" % (cwd, files))

inputFolder = r'C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\Desktop\Afternoon' ## Change here the input folder

i=0

for file in os.listdir(inputFolder):
    if file.endswith(".html"):
        i=i+1

        suffix=".xlsx"
        #name = str(file) + "\b\b\b\b" + "xlsx"
        #out= r'C:/Users/Ahmed_Abdelmuniem/Desktop/Evening/%s' % (name)
        out= r'C:/users/Ahmed_Abdelmuniem/Desktop/Evening/%d%s' % (i,suffix)
        print(str(out))
        parser = ExcelParser(file)
        parser.to_excel(out)
```